# What are the important specifications to look for in a 3-phase system?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, three-phase

I was going through this [app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidub87/tidub87.pdf) and I want to understand what the specifications of the 3-phase (input) system are.

Like, what is the input voltage range, current and maximum power that can be delivered?

Can someone tell me where it is mentioned in the app note? I am unable to find it.

Comment: Go look at figure 21 on page 26. From my understanding, you need external component that will be selected based on your needs.

Comment: What three-phase input system? Level 1 and 2 charging use single-phase AC grid connections as input, level 3 charging uses DC. The specs of level 1 and 2 power input are in table 1 on page 2. Whatever sits before the AC input from the grid is outside of the scope of the app note.